# Add hibernate project to struts2 project

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I have created java project say (project 1) in eclipse with hibernate. 
and then Created a struts 2 project and I added project 1 to struts 2 project i got an error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
```

While sending request to action. how can I fix it.

Comment: Make sure all dependencies are being deployed.

Comment: Eclipse has an option to export libraries, or even in new versions a deployment assembly.

Comment: can any one explain how to solve the problem ?

Comment: Probably you should explain that a mess with projects?

Comment: when I run struts 2 model with a main method and run as java application . it works but while running in server it throws exceptions java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration

Comment: The server doesn't know about hibernate.